# Criar e salvar arquivo de texto(.txt) com vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, layout, txt

**Layout Utilizado**
Nomenclatura: XXXXXX_DDMMYYYY_ZZZZZ.TXT
DD = DIA / MM = MÊS / YYYY = ANO:
XXXXXX = Será um código fixo com 6 dígitos com
zeros a esquerda.
ZZZZZ = Será um sequencial do arquivo com 5 dígitos com zeros a esquerda.

Comment: O que já fez até agora?

Comment: Como tenho um modelo de como o arquivo deverá ficar, eu criei uma rotina que lê um arquivo já pronto(coisa que irei precisar também).  Não sei com pegar esses campos da tabela e gerar esse arquivo .txt.

Comment: Você deve [edit] a pergunta e postar pra gente ver onde está com dificuldade.

Comment: @bigown como disse acima. Não sei gerar arquivos txt.